# Sort array alphabetically by specific string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array of plans:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-base
        [plan_name] => Tier 1 - NYC
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-la-base
        [plan_name] => Tier 1 - LA
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-sf-base
        [plan_name] => Tier 1 - SF
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-core
        [plan_name] => Tier 2 - NYC
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-la-core
        [plan_name] => Tier 2 - LA
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-sf-core
        [plan_name] => Tier 2 - SF
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-la-unlimited
        [plan_name] => Tier 3 - LA
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-sf-unlimited
        [plan_name] => Tier 3 - SF
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [plan_id] => corporate-unlimited
        [plan_name] => Tier 3 - NYC
    )

)
```

I want them to be grouped by city like:

> Tier 1 - LA
>
> Tier 2 - LA
>
> Tier 3 - LA
>
> Tier 1 - NYC
>
> Tier 2 - NYC
>
> Tier 3 - NYC
>
> Tier 1 - SF
>
> Tier 2 - SF
>
> Tier 3 - SF

I tried to use `array_multisort()` but it displays all Tier 1 first then Tier 2 and then Tier 3.

Currently, I'm doing 3 `foreach` loops to group them into 3 cities but it's not flexible and I think it's too long. What could be the quickest/easiest way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), using a sort function which extracts the city name out of the `plan_name` value using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). If the city names are the same, we extract the tier number so we can sort by that instead:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $city_a = explode('-', $a['plan_name'])[1];
    $city_b = explode('-', $b['plan_name'])[1];
    if ($city_a == $city_b) {
        // sort by tier
        $tier_a = (int)explode(' ', $a['plan_name'])[1];
        $tier_b = (int)explode(' ', $b['plan_name'])[1];
        return $tier_a - $tier_b;
    }
    else {
        return strcmp($city_a, $city_b);
    }
});
```

I haven't included the output as it is quite long but you can see it in this [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/H92ke)

This is an alternate version which use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to extract the city and tier from each `plan_name`:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    preg_match('/^Tier\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\w+)$/', $a['plan_name'], $matches_a);
    preg_match('/^Tier\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\w+)$/', $b['plan_name'], $matches_b);
    // are the cities the same?
    if ($matches_a[2] == $matches_b[2]) {
        // yes, sort by tier
        return $matches_a[1] - $matches_b[1];
    }
    else {
        // no, sort by city
        return strcmp($matches_a[2], $matches_b[2]);
    }
});
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dQ1So)

Comment: @jeepers_creepers I've updated my answer with a couple of solutions that will also sort on the tier number